# How to play rtsp stream in android using ffmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, rtsp, rtsp-client

I want to play rtsp stream using ffmpeg library. I was buid ffmpeg for android and also I try to save rtsp stream to file it's work fine.
my command `ffmpeg -i rtsp://@URL -acodec copy -vcodec copy abc.mp4`

now I want to view my ip camera live stream video using ffmpeg. Have any ideas.

Thanks for ur time.

Comment: Hi msj  i am  working on project which having the same requirement u have but i am unable to save the streaming video, I am using this (https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) library.  can you please help  me what steps you follow  to make ffmpeg library, Thanks.

Comment: use `ffmpeg -i rtsp://@URL -acodec copy -vcodec copy abc.mp4` command. give your rtsp url to @url and also output path to abc.mp4. it's save stream as video file.

Comment: Yes , i use the same command but is not working for rtsp stream, its works only on local videos. Can you suggest which ffmpeg library you used.

Comment: I follow to build ffmpeg [roman10 tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/)  and `rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov` link work fine. Have you any idea to play rtsp stream in android

Comment: Thanks for your support, sorry i have no idea to play rtsp stream in android.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using this command?

`ffplay -rtsp_transport http rtsp://@URL -acodec copy -vcodec copy`

I got it from this link

https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp

Answer (score 0):

To play an rtsp stream in Android: if you don't wish to use the command line ffmpeg tools but access the ffmpeg library directly I recommend; https://github.com/potterhsu/RtspLibrary.

(Note if you wish to save the rtsp stream to disk using the ffmpeg command line tools I recommend https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android).